# Crystal Reports: Add a parameter to query

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using the Crystal Reports add-on to Visual Studio. The report calls a stored procedure with a whole list of parameters. I added an int parameter to the stored procedure, now I want to make the crystal report pass a 1 for that parameter.

How do I do that? When I go to database expert > Selected Tables - it just shows the name of the stored procedure. Where does it list the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

If you already created the report and added the parameter to the stored procedure after that you need to use "Verify Database" to get the parameter to the report

Comment: Ok, but how do I add the parameter to the call to the stored procedure? I just don't see anywhere to do that and I'm stuck. Does it have to do with the Field Definition ttx file?

Comment: did you use "Verify database" ?

Comment: Yes. That displayed a dialog prompting me to enter values for all the original parameters, not the new one.

Comment: Any chance the missing parameter is declared as an output parameter ? Are you sure the connection is pointing to the right database ?

Comment: No and yes, but in the meantime we figured out that the problem is in the call from the webpage to the crystal activex and not in the report itself. Thank you for your help!